# Bulk inserts fail while switching partitions

Tags: sql-server, ssis, partition

I have a partitioned table. parttiion key is SiteID.
I load data from different sites concurrently. I first truncate a partition (tried both partition truncation and partition switching) and then load data to that partition.
This is doneby SSIS.
Sometimes while loading data,another session truncates a different partition belonging to the same table.
The partition truncation raises the followingerror:

> An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record
>   is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" 
>   Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Insert bulk failed due to a schema
>   change of the target table.".

Is there any way to prevent that issue?